# Error while installing Omnet++ on Ubuntu 16.04 : Cannot find osgEarth

Tags: 16.04, configure

I followed the installation guide and installed all the packages mentioned. However, I end up with this error message while running ./configure

```
checking for osgEarth with CFLAGS=" -fPIC  -fno-stack-protector  " LIBS="  -losgEarth -losgEarthUtil"... no
configure: error: Cannot find osgEarth 2.7 or later. Set WITH_OSGEARTH=no in configure.user to disable this feature or install an up to date version of osgEarth.
```

Here is a link to my config.log file : [config.log](https://pastebin.com/JzhsCZu3)

Comment: Please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209819/omnet-on-ubuntu-14-06-error-in-make-file/50213942#50213942 → `sudo apt install libosgearth-dev` etc. etc. Build prerequisites. ( No usable `libosgearth-dev` for 16.04 )  And please follow my well tested "Build example".

Comment: Thanks for responding.. I'd like to know what you mean by "usable" libosgearth-dev ?

Comment: The linked text says: » version 2.7 required. Not available, Ubuntu 16.04 «. .... The Ubuntu 16.04 version is `libosgearth-dev_2.5.0`, i.e. not usable, when version 2.7.0 is required. Hence `./configure WITH_OSGEARTH=no`

Comment: I had actually installed version 2.7 before asking this question :) Which is why I was confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the `libgeos-dev` package, and then editing the `configure.user` file in my OMnet++ source directory solved my problem.

`$ sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev`

Change the line `#OSGEARTH_LIBS=` to this: 
`OSGEARTH_LIBS=" -losgEarth -losgEarthUtil -lgeos_c "` 
Make sure to remove the # in the beginning.

Now run:

```
$ . setenv
$ ./configure
```

And it should work..

Others have also faced this problem before and have the fix mentioned here solved their issues:
http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/boards/1/topics/4621
https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/changeset/11363

Answered by Attila Török on the omnetpp google group (omnetpp@googlegroups.com)

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot find osgEarth 2.7 or later

I found `osgEarth 2.7` for Ubuntu 16.04 in the "ubuntugis repo" :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install g++ libxml2-dev libosgearth-dev bison flex clang swig libqt5opengl5-dev qt5-qmake openjdk-8-jre libopenmpi-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev
```

And now you get osgEarth **2.7** and can do `export QT_SELECT=5 && ./configure` in omnetpp-5.3/.

... All requirements are then included in the config result. ( The ancient `Akaroa (optional)` usually fails building.)

---

Some hints here about "osgEarth": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304274/error-while-installing-omnet-on-ubuntu-16-04-cannot-find-osgearth/50335148#50335148

`configure.user` >>> `OSGEARTH_LIBS=" -losgEarth -losgEarthUtil -lgeos_c "`

Comment: I had used the ubuntugis repo before asking this question.. Shows the same message with osgEarth 2.7.. Thanks for answering anyways.. I've asked this question in the mailing groups too. Will update once I get an answer

Comment: Strange. I installed `libosgearth-dev libopenmpi-dev`, ran `export QT_SELECT=5 && ./configure && make` in Ubuntu 16.04 : No errors. ... Are you sure you installed **libosgearth-dev** ? And got **2.7** ? Please do a 'status' check → `dpkg -s libosgearth-dev`

Comment: It shows the package as installed..

Comment: Please add the command, and the output to your question : `dpkg -s libosgearth-dev`

Comment: Are you quite sure that all the prerequisites are installed? `sudo apt install g++ libxml2-dev libosgearth-dev bison flex clang swig libqt5opengl5-dev qt5-qmake openjdk-8-jre libopenmpi-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev`